# Angular PWA : caching configuration json

Tags: angular, manifest, service-worker, angular-service-worker, angular-pwa

I want to active PWA I success to cache all assets but configuration JSON not caching
so my app didn't work correctly in offline mode

FYI: I try this in real server with https  but the same results so I work in virtual server
"ngsw.json"

```
"dataGroups": [
{
  "name": "data",
  "patterns": [
    "https:\\/\\/devtst01\\.dd\\/mazservice\\/AbpUserConfiguration\\/.*",
    "https:\\/\\/devtst01\\.dd\\/mazservice\\/(?:.+\\/)?.*"
  ],
  "strategy": "performance",
  "maxSize": 8,
  "maxAge": 86400000,
  "timeoutMs": 10000,
  "version": 1
}]
```

- mainfest screen
  [image]
- service worker screen
  [image]
- this is my chrome audites
  [image]
- this snap from the network in offline mode [image]

thanks in advance

Comment: Your setup seems correct as SW is correctly installed. If you write the whole target url (without regex) does it cache the response? Also note that the last path segment of the url cannot have a "." (dot), as it would be considered as file extension. I wrote a step by step guide about Angular PWAs: https://dev.to/paco_ita/create-progressive-web-apps-with-angular-workbox-pwa-builder-step-4-27d#angular if you want to have a look at it.